# Masking pixels in image collection using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to mask pixels based on the quality band information for image collection Landsat 5. This is my code but the image-collection is empty afterward.

Can you help me?

```js
var startDate = '1992-01-01'
var endDate =   '1993-01-01'
var cloudCover = 30
var collection1992 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 170))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 32))
                        .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
                        .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',cloudCover)
                        .sort('system:time_start')
// cloud mask 66,130
var collection1992_noclouds = collection1992.map(function(img) {
                var mask1 = img.select('pixel_qa').eq(66).eq(130)
                return img.UpdateMask(mask1)
                    })
Map.addLayer(collection1992_noclouds, {}, 'collection1992_noclouds')
```

Comment: As a side note, `updateMask` is not capitalized like you spelled it in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The collection is *not* empty; rather, it contains images which are entirely masked.

```js
var mask1 = img.select('pixel_qa').eq(66).eq(130)
```

This line

- takes the `pixel_qa` band,
- transforms it into an image which is 1 wherever the value was 66 and 0 otherwise,
- and then compares *that* with 130.

So the mask is always zero the way you have constructed it.

Did you mean that you want to select values of 66 *or* 130? Then you need to compare against both and combine them. Here's one way to do that:

```js
var collection1992_noclouds = collection1992.map(function(img) {
  var pixel_qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  return pixel_qa.eq(66).max(pixel_qa.eq(130));
});
```