# Removing pixels in band using an inequality in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, landsat-8

My current code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ff735e22e894a6c1b5ddc628cfccae7

I have an inequality from line 99-106.  I want this inequality to assign a value of 1 to all pixels that satisfy the inequality and remove all pixels that do not satisfy the inequality to be removed entirely.

At the moment, it creates a binary image where pixels that are less than the threshold have a value of 0 and pixels that are greater than the threshold have a value of 1.

I have set an image to automatically display for testing purposes (black = 0, teal= 1.  I ultimately want to have the displayed image on have teal that will change in extent as the inequality threshold changes.

Comment: You can't "remove" pixels, but you can make a mask based on your binary image to apply to other images or imagecollections; e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283415/how-to-mask-pixels-in-image-collection Masked pixels will not be considered for calculations.